# Появились ли в Стандарте С++ отражения?

Tags: c++

Есть у меня проект интерпретатора Basic, написанный на С++. Проект довольно давний, ему уже лет 20. Соответственно, начинался этот проект на заре использования С++.

В процессе написания интерпретатора выяснилось, что для задачи интерпретатора полезно было бы иметь возможность передавать информацию с этапа трансляции на этап выполнения. В частности, чтобы подключить пользовательские функции к исполняющей системе интерпретатора, хорошо бы иметь возможность передавать информацию об аргументах С++ функций с этапа трансляции на этап выполнения. Эти возможности называли тогда отражениями и тогда эти возможности отсутствовали в С++. Тем не менее, ходили разговоры, что эти возможности будут добавлены в С++.

В связи с этим вопросы:

1. Появились ли в Стандарте С++ отражения?
2. Если нет, то ожидаются ли или от отражений отказались?

Comment: Нет. Не слышал, чтобы их собирались добавлять...

Comment: К сожалению, отсутствие приветствий — это стандарт у нас. Но стандарты можно поменять через Мету. Если вы придёте на Мету и переубедите большинство, то правила поменяются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Нет, в C++ всё ещё нет *отражений* (reflections).
2. Да, работа над ними ведётся. Вот [одно](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0194r3.html) из предложений.

Когда мы сможем их увидеть в стандарте? Неизвестно, но это одна из тех функциональностей, которую многие ждут. Тем более, что тепло принятые [метаклассы](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0707r0.pdf) завязаны на отражения.

Comment: Thanks. Однако, как я понял, метаклассы тоже еще не введены в Стандарт и остаются пока только на уровне предложений.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, конечно, они ведь зависят от отражений. Всё это вряд ли появится раньше 23 года. Хотя, теоретически, отражения могут в 20-м появиться.